# Is it possible to modify ATS settings programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-transport-security

I have an app where users can enter different urls to communicate with different servers.

Apples App Transport Security is a bit of a nightmare when it comes to allowing users to enter urls.

My options that I know of right now:

1. Turn off ATS.  Don't like this as all traffic is not protected.
2. Turn on ATS and when users enter a URL that is not compliant with ATS it will fail. This is the most secure but very limiting if they want to go to a server that does not provide ssl or is using a weak SHA.

It would be nice to let my users enter a url, then determine if ATS fails.  If it fails it would be nice to prompt the user letting them know the sever is insecure and then add an exception programmatically if they confirm.

So the question is, can I programmatically change the ATS settings and add exceptions to ATS?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I think you're misinterpreting the purpose of ATS, but there are provisions for doing what you want. ATS is not designed to conditionally validate, it's to enforce an OS-specific set of best practices on all (or at least a specified subset) of network connections.  For most simple applications, this is sufficient as they access a limited number of either highly-visible sites or sites that they control.  In your case, you need the a validation capability potentially to prompt the user for whether it's OK to connect to an insecure site, or maybe use an internal, or hosted whitelist for badly-configured sites.

I have an app that also allows connections to arbitrary servers, especially ones that may be set up by a different organization and thus may have very different views of upgrade cycles and security.   For this kind of setup, a whitelist-style (Apple's default) isn't really appropriate, because we need the flexibility to support poorly-secured sites (or at least self-signed certificates until people use Let's Encrypt more).

For our purposes, we use a blacklist-style for ATS.  Basically we know that sites we control and well-known sites are going to be at higher levels of security, so we force ATS to enforce on those sites.  For all other sites, ATS is disabled, allowing non-SSL and poorly-configured SSL to be used.

In order to perform your own checking, you'll need to implement an `NSURLSessionDelegate` and use the `URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:` to make your own decisions about the validity of the SSL/TLS connection.

Inside of your handler, you can do basically any verification you deem appropriate, and since it has a `completionHandler` block, you can even prompt the user before continuing.

We use this method for allowing the user to choose after showing details of the certificate, and also use it for a form of certificate pinning.  In the pinning case, we basically save the fingerprint of the site certificate and use that to determine if the user OK'd the site (much safer than using the site's name, as the user validates the authority or the certificate and not just the URL).

For the sake of completeness, when I refer to "blacklist-style" above, I'm referring specifically to using `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to to `YES`, and using `NSExceptionDomains` to specifically list domains you know should be secure (such as your own servers, or well known services).  This involves setting `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` to `NO` for the entries in the exception table.

Comment: Can you also check for the encryption used by the server in this case?  IE warn if sha1?

Comment: @lostintranslation The session itself allows for setting `TLSMinimumSupportedProtocol`, but I'm not aware of a way to read the current status, so you may need to walk down the types if you need to enforce the protocol settings.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to do this in iOS. And even more importantly, at WWDC this year, Apple announced that all apps in the App Store must have ATS enabled by the end of this year.  In the session, it did state that exceptions will be allowed on a case by case basis, but you need to have a valid reason.  I'm not sure if yours is a valid reason (user-entered server names), only Apple will know for sure.

One correction to a statement in your question:

> Turn off ATS. Don't like this as all traffic is not protected.

Option 1 does not leave all traffic unprotected.  Disabling ATS only means that Apple can't guarantee that the app's traffic is protected.  If you are connecting to a server using SSL with an appropriately strong key and forward secrecy, **that** connection will be secure.  But it also allows you to connect to a different server over HTTP, providing little in the form of protection.  So option 1 doesn't strip any security, it just means your users can't expect all server related traffic to be secure.

Do the user-entered URLs offer any pattern that you could use to put in a domain name based exception in the ATS in the Info.plist?

Comment: Thanks @wottle!  Bummer is that is the answer I expected but was hoping I missed something.  The not protected issue is more of protecting against man in the middle attacks.  If ATS is off, even if I hit a server using SSL appropriately someone can 'fake' that server cert and my app (with ATS) off will still accept that 'invalid' connection.  No matter tho, seems like I am going to have to come up with a better idea.